# Javascript to create data attributes into table cells

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I use the following code to add data attributes into table cells, but only for one single table on page. How can it be modified to add data attributes to all existing tables on page?

Thank you in advance

```
    var headertext = [],
headers = document.querySelectorAll("#product-table th"),
tablerows = document.querySelectorAll("#product-table th"),
tablebody = document.querySelector("#product-table tbody");

for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  var current = headers[i];
  headertext.push(current.textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/,""));
} 
for (var i = 0, row; row = tablebody.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[j]);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you were calling `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()`.

Making that adjustment gives you a collection of tbody (instead of just the first one), which also means your looping logic needed to be adjusted.

See the below for detail.

```
var headertext = [],
    headers = document.querySelectorAll("#product-table th"),
    tablerows = document.querySelectorAll("#product-table tr"),
    //*** querySelectorAll() instead of querySelector() ***
    tablebody = document.querySelectorAll("#product-table tbody");

//...

//*** add this loop to iterate through each found tablebody element ***
for(var k = 0, tb; tb = tablebody[k]; k++)
    for (var i = 0, row; row = tb.rows[i]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[j]);
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Tried that. Same result as the original code. Works for the first table but no result on the others.

Comment: Did you try changing the commented like to "tr" instead of "th"?

It could be that your other tables are structured differently, and don't have and "tbody" or "th" elements.

Comment: Yes I changed it. The other tables are identical.

Comment: Something seems fishy. Can you throw together a JSFiddle with your markup and this script?

Comment: Working now. I modified the answer.